# Resetting the server side badge counter when new push notification arrives

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode

I am currently working on a push notification service for my iOS app.

Notifications will be pushed to the device correctly with the badge. After reading the notification, I can clear the badge count in the icon. However, when a new notification arrives, the badge count is increased by the previous count.

How can I clear the badge counter in the Server side using UIApplication delegate? Please give me some tips.

Comment: I think that if you send a badge count of 0 from the server, then the badge will disappear.

Comment: but i want to reset the badge counter after reading the notification in the client side...how can i do that from client side using Objective-c

Answer (score 0):

In your AppDelegate, use this code:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

Comment: ya i tried that already.it can clear only the client side counter,i want to clear the server side counter from client side..when we update the info of subscriber from the push server means it's clearing it's counter,so if new notification arrives means it will start from 1..but that's not the proper way,we can't do that every time...so is there any possibilities to reset the server counter from client side after reading the every notification...

Comment: You want the iphone to reset the server data? Just use a simple web-service that enables you to reset the badge count.

Comment: For example, every time the user loads the app you will send a GET request to http://www.yoursite.com/api/resetBadge/user-id. Your server will reset that user badge count in your database.

Comment: how it can be implemented using UIAppDelegate in Objective-c

Comment: i am currently working on push notification service for ios apps.i can receive notification from server and clear the badge count after reading the notification successfully,but what my problem is when a new notification arrives means it is adding to the previous badge count,so i think i need to reset the server side badge counter.....i can reset it from the server side,but i want to do that action from client side.i have used objective-c for creating the app.please help me.....